# Mark freestyle edge to all objects in a collection with Python

Tags: python, scripting

I'm a new Blender user and just started trying python. I want to apply Mark freestyle edge to all objects in a collection with code instead of doing it manually.

If I have objects selected in object mode & used the code below it works:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

    bpy.ops.mesh.mark_freestyle_edge(clear=False)
```

I'll like to do the same but without having to select objects first. I found this but I can't combine them into one script.

```
import bpy


col = bpy.data.collections.get("Collection_name")
if col:
   for obj in col.objects:
       obj.select_set(state=True)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I did some more research and found the solution.

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.collections['wireframe'].all_objects: obj.select_set(True)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

bpy.ops.mesh.mark_freestyle_edge(clear=False)
```